# straight edge between big nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, node-connections, edge

I have two rectangle nodes and want to put an edge between them. I want the edge have its arrow between the top center and the top left end of the lower node. I tried to do this with specifying in and out angle, however, this bends the line and makes the arrow look very ugly:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle] (u1) at (3,8) {run $A$};
    \node[draw,rectangle,align=left] (nextYES) at (3,6.5) {choose $(x,y,z)\\in V_{\mathbb{H}^3{'}}$\\ with $|L(x,y,z)| > 1$};
    \draw (u1) edge[->,>=latex,out=225,in=150] (nextYES);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make the edge straight, with the edge anchored at the current point (or somewhere nearby) and not turning the arrow at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `in`, `out` will result in a curved path; to get a staright line with the required specifications you have several possibilities:

1. Use the `<point>.<angle>` anchors:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
     *\begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw,rectangle] (u1) at (3,8) {run $A$};
       \node[draw,rectangle,align=left] (nextYES) at (3,6.5) {choose $(x,y,z)$\\in $V_{\mathbb{H}^3{'}}$\\ with $|L(x,y,z)| > 1$};
       \draw (u1.230) edge[->,>=latex] (nextYES.140);
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Use (possible shifts) and anchors:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw,rectangle] (u1) at (3,8) {run $A$};
       \node[draw,rectangle,align=left] (nextYES) at (3,6.5) {choose $(x,y,z)$\\in $V_{\mathbb{H}^3{'}}$\\ with $|L(x,y,z)| > 1$};
       \draw (u1.south) edge[->,>=latex] (nextYES.north west);
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw,rectangle] (u1) at (3,8) {run $A$};
       \node[draw,rectangle,align=left] (nextYES) at (3,6.5) {choose $(x,y,z)$\\in $V_{\mathbb{H}^3{'}}$\\ with $|L(x,y,z)| > 1$};
       \draw ([xshift=15pt]u1.south west) edge[->,>=latex] ([xshift=15pt]nextYES.north west);
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
3. Use the `calc` library to get some intermediate points (perhaps an overkill here):

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[draw,rectangle] (u1) at (3,8) {run $A$};
       \node[draw,rectangle,align=left] (nextYES) at (3,6.5) {choose $(x,y,z)$\\in $V_{\mathbb{H}^3{'}}$\\ with $|L(x,y,z)| > 1$};
       \draw 
       ( $ (u1.south west)!0.25!(u1.south east) $ ) edge[->,>=latex] 
       ( $ (nextYES.north west)!0.15!(nextYES.north east) $ );
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: (+1) Though I read the question differently....

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want straight lineS rather than a single line between one point and the other? For example:

[image: straight turns]

The reason I suggest this is because I can see the logic of trying the `in`-`out` angles in this case.

If so, you might use something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle] (u1) at (3,8) {run $A$};
    \node[draw,rectangle,align=left] (nextYES) at (3,6.5) {choose $(x,y,z)$\\$in V_{\mathbb{H}^3{'}}$\\ with $|L(x,y,z)| > 1$};
    \draw [->,>=latex] (u1.south) -- +(0,-5pt) -| ([xshift=5pt]nextYES.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that you cannot use `\\` within `$...$`. You need to exit maths mode, break the line and re-enter maths mode if a break is required.